# Telling an unmanned aircraft from its flight path

Tags: military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, flight-tracking

I'm not a hardcore fan of aircraft - I just like to know what is flying overhead and why...

Some days I hear this loud annoying droning sound coming from the sky - it's usually a military unmanned craft doing strange flight paths.

Is there a way to tell if a craft is unmanned because of its flight path or sound because of the 'way' it flies the plane?
Apparently it is a Diamond DA40 NG - SkyVan or Flying Shoebox! No owner showing up.

[image: SX-AEN on Flightaware]
([flightaware.com](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/SXAEN))

Comment: "*No owner showing up*", no but [from the markings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3QwF.jpg), it belongs to the fleet of a flying school,  [Egnatia Aviation](https://egnatia-aviation.aero/). You can see a touch and go at Mytilíni in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=lM7_9YCekWI&t=10m33s), and there are pilots onboard ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where people are obtaining the A/C type from this, but, judging from th  Ed flight path and SX-AEN’s previous flights, it appears to be a training aircraft based out of Philippi, Greece, and the flight path indicated above, appears to be an instrument training flight, probably early to mid phase of training for an instrument rating, including holding patterns, DME arcs, and procedure turns.

If it is, in fact, a diamond DA 40, or Shorts Skyvan, it is almost certainly not an unmanned aircraft, as both of those types require a human flight crew aboard in order to operate.

Comment: Well done also explaining what is (likely) going on there 

Comment: Source for aircraft type: [Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/sx-aen)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot distinguish manned from unmanned aircraft based on the flight path or sound. The best way to distinguish them is to identify the aircraft type, either visually or via a flight tracking website (like you have done).

The aircraft in your screenshot is a [Diamond DA40](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/en/private-owners/aircraft/da40/overview/):
[image: DA40 example]
<sup>([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Diamond_DA40_(8736184864).jpg))</sup>

This is a single engine piston aircraft, which is **always manned**:

> 18. Minimum Flight Crew: 1 (Pilot)

<sup>([EASA Type Certificate Data Sheet for the DA40](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/document-library/type-certificates/aircraft-cs-25-cs-22-cs-23-cs-vla-cs-lsa/easaima022-diamond-da))</sup>

This type of aircraft is often used for flight training. The flight path shown in your screenshot looks like it could be a training flight. If you are sure that it's a military aircraft, then it's probably flight training for the Hellenic Air Force.